# Regular expression help: how to ignore every path that isn’t a CSS file

Tags: ruby, regex, middleman, file-globs

I have a CSS framework submodule in my Git repo that includes a bunch of `README`, `component.json` and other files. I don’t want to modify or delete the files because I’d imagine it’d cause problems when updates are pushed to the submodule. Yet Middleman wants to process them.

I currently have this in my `config.rb` file:

```
# Ignore everything that's not a CSS file inside inuit.css
ignore 'css/inuit.css/*.html'
ignore 'css/inuit.css/*.json'
ignore 'css/inuit.css/LICENSE'
```

How could I express this with a file pattern or a regex?

Comment: It would help if you didn't have folders with `.css` in their names.  `_css` would be better.  Then it's a matter of using a regex that matches `.css` at the end of the file name.  Otherwise you need to check whether things like `inuit.css` are folders or files.

Comment: Those aren't regular expressions.  Those are file matching patterns, or fileglobs.

Comment: @AndyLester According to [Middleman’s documentation](http://middlemanapp.com/dynamic-pages/index.html), “you can give `ignore` exact source paths, filename globs, or regexes.”

Comment: It may allow you to ignore using regexes, but `css/inuit.css/*.html` is a filename glob, not a regex.

Comment: @AndyLester Oh, I know that. I was just indicating that regexes *could* be used in this question. And the answer probably will use regexes, since they are more powerful than file globs.

Comment: Here’s [a regex starting point with example file paths to test on](http://rubular.com/r/hFHTfSW8Er). That regex in that link matches *only* CSS files, the opposite of what we want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’m not familiar with Middleman, but doesn’t this work?

```rb
ignore /^css\/inuit\.css\/.*(?<![.]css)$/
```

Comment: That also needs an `i` flag to that so it can handle “.CSS” files, but if you add `i` then yes, that should work – it [passes my test cases](http://rubular.com/r/93F65OcOt3). Good use of [negative lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookbehind) `(?<!)`.

Answer (score 1):

Since `ignore` [can take a regex](http://middlemanapp.com/dynamic-pages/index.html), pass `ignore` a Ruby regex `//` instead of a string `""` with a filename glob. In the regex, use [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookahead) `(?!)` and the [end-of-string anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) `$` to check that the filename doesn’t end in “.css”.

```rb
ignore /^ css\/inuit\.css\/ (?:  [^.]+  |  .+ \. (?!css) \w+   ) $/ix
```

This regex [correctly handles all of these test cases](http://rubular.com/r/6d8KcgsJRD):

- Should match:

  - `css/inuit.css/abc.html`
  - `css/inuit.css/thecssthing.json`
  - `css/inuit.css/sub/in_a_folder.html`
  - `css/inuit.css/sub/crazily.named.css.json`
  - `css/inuit.css/sub/crazily.css.named.json`
  - `css/inuit.css/LICENSE`
- Shouldn’t match:

  - `css/inuit.css/realcss.css`
  - `css/inuit.css/main.css`
  - `css/inuit.css/sub/in_a_folder.css`
  - `css/inuit.css/sub/crazily.css.named.css`
  - `css/inuit.css/sub/crazily.named.css.css`

The first alternation of the `(?:)` non-capturing group handles the case of files with no extension (no “.”). Otherwise, the second case checks that the last “.” in the path is not followed by “css”, which would indicate a “.css” extension.

I use the `x` flag to ignore whitespace in the regex, so that I can add spaces in the regex to make it clearer.